How to apply Vandermonde's Identity regarding summation bounds ? $\sum_{t=0}^n\binom{-k-1}{t-k}\binom{-j-1}{n-t-j}=\binom{-k-j-2}{n-j-k}$
from the answer: Proof of the hockey stick/Zhu Shijie identity $\sum\limits_{t=0}^n \binom tk = \binom{n+1}{k+1}$

this happens from step 4 to 5:
$$
\sum_{t=0}^n\binom{-k-1}{t-k}\binom{-j-1}{n-t-j}=\binom{-k-j-2}{n-j-k}
$$
if I apply the identity on the result, I get:
$$
\binom{m+n}{r}=\sum_{k=0}^r\binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{r-k}\\\\
\binom{-k-j-2}{n-j-k}=\sum_{t=0}^{n-j-k}\binom{-k-1}{t}\binom{-j-1}{(n-j-k)-t}
$$
my question is: how do you get $t-k$ on the bottom left ? (no variant of the identity seems to have that)
and what you do regarding the summation bounds ? ($(n-j-k)$ as upper bound doesn't seem equivalent)

(I copied the answer in case it gets edited):
$$
\binom{-n}{k}=(-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}{k}\tag{1}
$$
Here is a generalization of the identity in question, proven using the Vandermonde Identity
\begin{align*}
\sum_{t=0}^n\binom{t}{k}\binom{n-t}{j}
&=\sum_{t=0}^n\binom{t}{t-k}\binom{n-t}{n-t-j}\tag{2}\\\\
&=\sum_{t=0}^n(-1)^{t-k}\binom{-k-1}{t-k}(-1)^{n-t-j}\binom{-j-1}{n-t-j}\tag{3}\\\\
&=(-1)^{n-j-k}\sum_{t=0}^n\binom{-k-1}{t-k}\binom{-j-1}{n-t-j}\tag{4}\\\\
&=(-1)^{n-j-k}\binom{-k-j-2}{n-j-k}\tag{5}\\\\
&=\binom{n+1}{n-j-k}\tag{6}\\\\
&=\binom{n+1}{j+k+1}\tag{7}
\end{align*}
Explanation:
$(2)$: $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$
$(3)$: apply $(1)$ to each binomial coefficient
$(4)$: combine the powers of $-1$ which can then be pulled out front
$(5)$: apply Vandermonde
$(6)$: apply $(1)$
$(7)$: $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$

Recall that
$$\binom{v}{m} = 0 \quad m>v \; \textrm{ or} \; m<0 $$
Note that in
$$S=\sum_{t=0}^n\binom{-k-1}{t-k}\binom{-j-1}{n-t-j}$$
If
$$ t<k \implies \displaystyle \binom{-k-1}{t-k}=0$$
and
$$ t>n-j \implies  \binom{-j-1}{n-t-j}=0$$
Hence we can write our sum with the following indexes:
$$S=\sum_{\color{red}{t=k}}^{\color{red}{n-j}}\binom{-k-1}{t-k}\binom{-j-1}{n-t-j}$$
Now do the change of variable $m=t-k$. By Vandermonde's:
$$S=\sum_{t=k}^{n-j}\binom{-k-1}{t-k}\binom{-j-1}{n-t-j} = \sum_{\color{red}{m=0}}^{\color{green}{n-j-k}}\binom{-k-1}{\color{red}{m}}\binom{-j-1}{\color{green}{n-j-k}-\color{red}{m}} = \binom{-k-j-2}{\color{green}{n-j-k}}$$

thanks, I needed some explanation for variable substitution inside summation bounds, $\sum _{t=k}^{t=n-j}$, lower bound: $m=t-k\Leftrightarrow m=( k) -k\Leftrightarrow m=0$, upper bound: $m=t-k\Leftrightarrow m=( n-j) -k\Leftrightarrow m=n-j-k$, $\sum _{m=0}^{m=n-j-k}$, is this the optimal way or correct way to think about substitution inside summation bounds ?

@Mr.Doge Hi, yes that is correct

See also properties 3 and 7 here (index shift): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Identities
